# Which quantum gravity theories do predict a growing number of space dimensions?

Tags: cosmology, universe, quantum-gravity

In [this 2013 Nature article](http://www.nature.com/news/theoretical-physics-the-origins-of-space-and-time-1.13613) there is a short presentation of the
causal dynamical triangulations approach to quantum gravity, where it is said

> Intriguingly, the simulations also hint that soon after the Big Bang,
>   the Universe went through an infant phase with only two dimensions —
>   one of space and one of time. This prediction has also been made
>   independently by others attempting to derive equations of quantum
>   gravity, and even some who suggest that the appearance of dark energy
>   is a sign that our Universe is now growing a fourth spatial dimension.
>   Others have shown that a two-dimensional phase in the early Universe
>   would create patterns similar to those already seen in the cosmic
>   microwave background.

but unfortunately there are no references to who the "some" and "others" are. What are these theories where the number of spatial dimensions of the universe is not constant over its history?

Comment: The article has a list of references. Did you look up those papers?

Comment: in each chapter there is a name attached to the theories, and  the name appears in the references. It is the way to find the pubications

Comment: Of course I did check the references. The single one pertaining to the CDT chapter is [this one](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0404156). That's reference number 10 in the article. The passage I cited comes after that, and talks about work from other people, to which no references are given, as stated in my question.

Comment: You are asking how to search on the web for new research. 1)take the names in the reference 10 and google.  A wiki article comes out : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_dynamical_triangulation , in the article a talk comes out:  http://loops05.aei.mpg.de/index_files/abstract_loll.html  .

Comment: @annav. I don't think there is an answer to my question in the video you linked. I am not looking for a presentation of CDT, but for pointers to the theories mentioned by the Nature article (which are not CDT if I can read correctly).

Comment: how about this http://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/0202346.pdf .for  "the appearance of dark energy is a sign that our Universe is now growing a fourth spatial dimension"

Comment: I think that this http://www.seeker.com/will-science-burst-the-multiverses-bubble-1768827015.html#news.discovery.com has to do with "two-dimensional phase in the early Universe would create patterns similar to those already seen in the cosmic microwave background." also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_string

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you searching on arxiv for the following names related to CDT:

- Renate Loll, Jan Ambjorn, Jerzy Jurkiewicz (the creators of CDT)
- Andrzej Görlich, Jakub-Gizbert Studnicki (currently with phd. hab. status at Jagiellonian University)
- Dániel Németh (its myself if you allow self advertisement) and Zbigniew Drogosz (currently PhD students under J. Jurkiewicz, working on the 3+1 CDT model, soon PhD, keywirds: phases, scalar fields, massive particles)
- Marcus Reitz (PhD) and Joren Burekreef (PhD student) under Renate Loll at Radbaud University, working on 1+1and 2+1 CDT, keywords: Wilson loops, laplacian)

-Timothy Budd, independent fellow at Radbaud working on different aspects of CDT

- Massimo D'elia (professor), Giuseppe Clemente (PhD) at Pisa University

And there are a few names. Type them to the search field in [arXiv](http://www.arxiv.org), and you will find a plenty of articles.